# What is the prediction tag for? Do we need it?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

I found the [prediction](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prediction) tag (**11** questions currently) on [Terraforming — when and where — current estimates?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54611/12102) where it was added by a new user assuming it belongs on questions about predicting future technology.

I removed it from that question.

Most of the rest of the uses are about predicting positions of objects in their orbits, but it's also found on [Predictive simulation of gait on Mars?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40635/12102)

Hmm... Is using [simulation](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simulation) (**102** questions) here instead better? Yes, so I've made that change as well.

Surely all of these uses shouldn't come from one tag.

**Questions:**

1. What is the prediction tag for? Should it be just for predicting positions of objects in their orbits, or should the definition be broader?
2. Do we need it at all? [orbital-mechanics](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orbital-mechanics) (**1,455** questions) is our most frequent tag. [prediction](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prediction) and [tracking](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tracking) (**108** questions) are things we do with orbits, but if we want to support the prediction tag it would have to be added to more orbital-mechanics questions to actually be useful for what it's supposed to represent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags that are overly broad and ill-defined aren't helpful.  I would remove it.

Comment: I think so too.

Comment: @uhoh I'm going to answer you here rather than the other thread that's not related. Mods can't delete tags, so the best course of action here is for people to manually remove it from each question. Then it will be automatically deleted by the system.