# Should we revive the developing-space-programs tag by adding it to all applicable questions, or just delete or combine with space-program?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, retagging

[developing-space-programs](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developing-space-programs) **7** questions:

> The developing-space-programs tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

seems to be an experiment that's run its course. While I think we've had some more recent questions about the birth of new space programs, including

- [What are the main issues addressed by New Zealand's recent rocket legislation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21634/12102)
- [Will Scotland require a space agency? Is there one in the works?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32373/12102)
- [What is the Austrian Space Forum doing in Oman?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26970/12102)

for example, they don't currently use the tag.

In fact, **the tag was used only between November 2013 and February 2014.**

**Question:** Should we revive the [developing-space-programs](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developing-space-programs) tag by adding it to all applicable questions, or either just delete it or perhaps somehow combine it with:

- [space-program](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-program) **12** questions

> The space-program tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

---

Here are the seven questions currently tagged [developing-space-programs](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developing-space-programs) from late 2013 to early 2014:

- [Do developing space programs generally use an existing booster design, or make their own from scratch?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2657/12102)
- [What is JAXA looking for on the Moon in the way of 'potential utilization'?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2659/12102)
- [Do any of the developing space programs use horizontal launcher assembly and launchpad loading?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2674/12102)
- [Are there any non-government owned, non-US based, companies that are in the process of developing manned spaceflight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2843/12102)
- [Any chance of seeing a vertical launch of an orbital launch vehicle in UK in the not-too-distant future?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2894/12102)
- https://space.stackexchange.com/a/3127/12102
- [What specifications is the ISRO crew module fabricated to?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3706/12102)

Comment: I'm inclined toward the merge option.

Comment: @called2voyage ya I agree 100%.

Comment: @called2voyage this seems like a good idea, is it something that's best implemented by a moderator? https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2851/12102